# Ansible: How to chmod +x a file with Ansible?

Tags: bash, ansible

What is the best way to chmod + x a file with ansible.

Converting the following script to ansible format.

```
mv /tmp/metadata.sh /usr/local/bin/meta.sh
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/meta.sh
```

This is what I have so far..

```
- name: move /tmp/metadata.sh to /usr/local/bin/metadata.sh
  command: mv /tmp/metadata.sh /usr/local/bin/metadata.sh
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

`ansible` has `mode` parameter in [`file`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html) module exactly for this purpose.

To add execute permission for everyone (i.e. `chmod a+x` on command line):

```
- name: Changing perm of "/foo/bar.sh", adding "+x"
  file: dest=/foo/bar.sh mode=a+x
```

Symbolic modes are supported since version 1.8, on a prior version you need to use the octal bits.

Comment: 2 years later and this answer helped me with an Ansible issue.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: @DustWolf - do you have a reference for that? I use symbolic mode exclusively and have not seen anything in the documentation stating that only octal is idempotent.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html

Answer (score 21):

The `mode` parameter should be specified when using the [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/copy_module.html) module.

Example:

```
- name: copy file and set permissions
  copy:
    src: script.sh
    dest: /directory/script.sh
    mode: a+x
```

Answer (score 6):

You can change the permission of a file without copy module.

```yaml
- name: Change permission on myScript.sh file
  file:
    path: /path/to/directory/myScript.sh
    state: file
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0755
```

Answer (score 1):

A good and verbose way of doing it while using the `copy` module is with the Ansible **symbolic mode**:

```
  copy:
    src: create_rules.sh
    dest: ~/rules/
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: u+rwx,g=,o=
```

The mode above is equivalent to `chmod 0700`

`u+rwx` means "give read(r), write(w) and execution(x) permissions to owner(u)", which is a `7` in the octal's second field '07'

You are able to do also `ug+rwx,o=` which is equivalent to `chmod 0770`.

Please notice to not use spacing after the comma.

The [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) also shows that `ug=rwx,o=` is O.K. too.